# How can I define a theme in a UWP Library?

Tags: xaml, uwp, resources, themes

I'm creating a UWP library that contains custom controls and I want to define a dark and light theme for my controls. I understand that we can add a theme resource dictionary to the App.xaml. We can specify a dark/light theme there and set the requested theme property. But since I am making a library,  I don't have an App.xaml in my project. Is it possbile for me to define a theme within the library project? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a resource dictionary file in Microsoft Visual Studio by using the **Add** > **New Item…** > **Resource Dictionary** option from the Project menu. Then we can define the `ThemeDictionaries` in the `ResourceDictionary` file.

For example:

```
    <ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:ClassLibrary1">
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomColor" Color="Orange" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomColor" Color="Blue" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomColor" Color="Green" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

To use that dictionary, we can merge it with control’s dictionary:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ClassLibrary1.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClassLibrary1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{ThemeResource CustomColor}" Width="500" Height="500"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to specify a dark/light theme, you can set `RequestedTheme` in the Control.

Comment: `RequestedTheme` is keyed to an `enum` with only 3 values. How do you set a custom theme name?